# EF - switch between Firebird and Oracle databases in runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, firebird

I used ASP.NET MVC, Entity Framework Model First and Firebird database.
Now we added Oracle database with same tables and fields and I want switch connection between Firebird and Oracle in runtime.

It is possible to use one data model for both databases ? Or, maybe, i need to create separate data models, but how I can used them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

If you create an EDMX for each DB with the exact same CSDL section and generate classes for only one of them, then you can create a context that connects to the DB you want by specifying the correct connection string (which includes the correct EDMX elements (SSDL, CSDL, MSL)).